# how can i make ubuntu software center offer 32-bit packages

Tags: 12.04, software-center, 64-bit, application-development, 32-bit

I am developing a 3D game/graphics/simulation engine on 64-bit ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  The 64-bit version of my application compiles, links and executes just fine.  However, I cannot build a 32-bit version of my application.  I get the following build errors:

```
ld : cannot find -lX11
ld : cannot find -lcairo
ld : cannot find -lpango
ld : cannot find -lfreetype
ld : cannot find -lfmodex
```

My assumption is, I do not have 32-bit versions of some libraries installed.  However, when I look for files with -i386 or :i386 suffix in "ubuntu software center", I don't see any.  For example, if I enter "libcairo" in the search field, it shows:

```
libcairo2
libcairo2-dev
libcairo2-doc
libcairo2-dbg
plus a other irrelevant files (bindings for other languages).
```

No matter how I search, I cannot see any package names that imply 32-bit libraries.

How, exactly, are we supposed to develop 32-bit executables on 64-bit linux circa 2012 and beyond (ubuntu 12.04 LTS in my case)?

Comment: **Pondering same issue.** I am just migrating my main PC to 64bit, but intend to keep a secondary machine for 32bit (or cross-platform) compilation.

Comment: That's not supposed to be necessary. A 64-bit operating system can run both 64-bit and 32-bit applications AND it is supposed to be possible to develop both 64-bit and 32-bit applications on 64-bit linux. In fact, before I switched to 64-bit ubuntu 12.04 LTS a week ago, I was developing my applications as both 64-bit and 32-bit on 64-bit ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Comment: LATER:  As it turns out, we still need to install the ia32-libs package to get many fundamental 32-bit shared libraries installed on our computers.

Comment: LATER: As it also turns out, once I installed the ia32-libs package on my computer, henceforth packages with :i386 started to appear in searches on "ubuntu software center".  Wow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Development packages* are usually architecture-independent. For everything else, to get the i386 (32-bit) libraries you need to install the `ia32-libs` package in Software Center. That should automatically pull in all the i386 libraries you may need (depending on the 64-bit ones already installed).

[image]

Comment: But someone else told me gcc-multilib and g++-multilib are the new and improved replacements for ia32-libs.  Is that wrong?

Comment: `gcc/g++-multilib` are the **cross-compilers** -- they do not contain all the possible 32-bit shared libraries in the world an applicatin may need to link to! :)    Those are provided by `ia32-libs`

Comment: So ia32-libs will be needed into the indefinite future on 64-bit operating systems? Someone said it was obsolete, or soon would be (replaced by "multiarch", "multilib" or something).

Comment: Okay, I installed ia32-libs, then make a whole slew of soft-links in directory /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu to point to the verbose shared library files. For example, the soft-links I created in directory /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu were: libX11.so libcairo.so, libpango.so, libpangocairo.so, libfmodex.so, etc). And **that did the trick** - I can now compile/link/execute the 32-bit versions of my 3D engine. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Ann -- multiarch was designed to ensure you don't have to do what you painstakingly did, but not all packages have been converted to multiarch yet, hence the need for ia32-libs. That's the short version, I'll edit the answer tomorrow to explain a little more about multiarch and how it affects cross-compiling, especially. :)

Comment: Personally, I use and highly recommend at least a chroot for cross-compiling 32-bit on 64-bit...